# Does NServiceBus have a use in Web/MVC4 + SQL architecture?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, nservicebus

Given that the web is a very one-way synchronous architecture, is there any benefit to an NSB-enabled web application using MVC4?

I love the fault tolerance and ease of development that comes with NSB, but since the technology is all about one-way asynchronous messaging, how can I design my application around it in such a way that the user doesn't (often) notice their commands not being complete by the time a postback occurs? What paradigm should I adopt in designing my UI to naturally fit the curvature of NServiceBus?

Indeed, it seems NSB is an unnecessary complexity between a website and its SQL store because users always assume the "work" is done when their browser is done refreshing. Am I wrong in this regard?

Edit: I've seen other solutions whereby each command handler publishes an event when the work is done by the NSB service, and that event handlers on the ASP.NET project will create "stub files" that a Java-script enabled page is constantly polling to indicate that an operation completed. Is this the only way to bridge the gap between one way sync and async platforms?

Comment: You should consider using NServiceBus with SignalR. You can have a hub containing a method that will notify the client for completing of a command. Where NServicebus will invoke the Hub Server code whenever a command is completed.

Comment: I looked into SignalR last night. I like it as a solution for duplex communication, but it won't buy me anything using NSB with the Web. The core problem is that commands may or may not be executed before a postback is complete. I suspect the answer is no, NSB is not very compatible with the Web, or that I need to radically approach User Inerface design differently.

Comment: Using SignalR could still work, if you store the command completion in a data store. And read it using SignalR when the postback is completed

Comment: Stop using SingalR to solve the wrong problems.

Comment: You don't have to use it for everything. I mostly use it for situations where a command can be fire and forget (i.e. send an email, sync some data to a 3rd party system etc). There may be cases where you want to know what happened in which case you can either use full duplex messaging or by using a pub/sub model whereby your command handlers publish an event when the command was complete and your webserver(s) subscribe to those events and push data down to the browsers using SignalR or similar. If using SignalR you'd really need to be using a SPA model for your web app though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NServiceBus fits in quite nicely with any web front-end.  You are just going to need to be aware of how asynchronous message processing affects your UI.  In most instances one could simply indicate to the user that the request has been accepted and will be processed.  But in other cases you may need to forgo eventual consistency for immediately consistent.

For instance, for user registration I typically check availability of the user name and then register the user immediately but I send a command to e-mail the activation message so that the user does not have to wait for that.  The user *will* eventually receive their e-mail.  So a message is displayed indicating that an e-mail will be sent and that they need to click the activation link even though the mail may only be sent in 5 minutes.

Another example is an application where the user could convert various document formats to TIFF.  The request would be sent and the web front-end would poll to wait for the result of the conversion and then display the converted pages.

So it is going to affect how your UI/UX works.  It is definitely still useful and in some instances makes your life a whole lot easier.

In my case I used my FOSS Shuttle Service Bus: http://shuttle.codeplex.com/ --- but the concepts apply anyway.

Comment: I like this answer because it offers a possible solution to the fact that Commands cannot be guaranteed to execute in the blink of an eye. I admit Udi came up with a similar plan of attack on a blog post of his regarding CQRS design.

Answer (score 3):

NServiceBus has hooks into the typical MVC web application that allow you to cause the user's postback to wait until a response arrives over the bus. See the AsyncPages sample to see how it's done.

Comment: It was a tough call but I selected Eben's answer because it offers some ideas for scenarios where Commands take "forever" to execute. I will say, for the record, the idea of sending emails when a command has completed is remarkably similar to your blog on CQRS implementation, something I am striving to implement (eventually.) Thank you for a fine product sir. :)